# calling function within a function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-api

In a nutshell, I want the following function to be executed when this button is clicked:

```
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="generateUpload();" />
```

But it does not seem to be responding and I receive zero error from console.

Below is the `generateUpload()` function, and I know whats inside that function works because I have tried to load the pages with it and the google drive picker would run but I only want it to run upon button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function generateUpload() 
{

   // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = 'id';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var clientId = 'id';

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,

              'immediate': true
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
              enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
              addView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
                 var message = 'The following(s) were stored in Parse: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;

        }
      }
}
</script>
```

Below is the button found in the body:

```
<input type="button" value="Create Short" onclick="generateUpload();" /> <br/>
```

Update:
below is the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>

  <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--======================================================================-->
<!--Custom website css file is linked here-->
<link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Font Awesome CSS link-->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



   <script>
   Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");



var module = angular.module("AuthApp", []);
module.controller("MyCntrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();

   $scope.userIdChanged = function () {
       $scope.loading = true;

       // now access $scope.userId here
       var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

       query.get($scope.userId, {
           success: function(userInfo) {
               // The object was retrieved successfully.
               var address = userInfo.get("Address");
               $scope.address = 'address: ' + address;

               var email = userInfo.get("Email");
               $scope.email = 'Email: ' + email;


                    var phone = userInfo.get("Phone");
               $scope.phone = 'Phone: ' + phone;

                 var scanURL = '<a href="scan.html">Scan</a>';
               $scope.scanURL = scanURL;
                          $scope.loading = false;


           },
           error: function(object, error) {
               // The object was not retrieved successfully.
               // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                          $scope.loading = false;

           }
       });
   };
});
</script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function generateUpload() 
{

    // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = 'ID';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var clientId = 'ID';

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,

              'immediate': true
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
              enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
              addView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
                 var message = 'The following(s) were stored in Parse: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;

        }
      }

      addOnOnApiLoadedCallback(onApiLoad); // register API load
}

var gapi_loaded = false, gapi_buffered_callbacks = [];
function onApiLoad() { // this function gets called by the Google API
    gapi_loaded = true;
    // run buffered callbacks
    for (var i = 0; i < gapi_buffered_callbacks.length; i += 1) {
        gapi_buffered_callbacks();
    }
}
function addOnOnApiLoadedCallback(callback) {
    if (gapi_loaded) {
        callback(); // api is loaded, call immediately
    } else {
        gapi_buffered_callbacks.push(callback); // add to callback list
    }

}

</script>

</head>
<body ng-app="AuthApp">


<div>
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-xs- col-centered col-fixed"><div class="item"><div class="content">
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
          <div ng-show="currentUser">
             <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

            <h2> Admin Panel </h2>
          </div></div></div></div>


                    <div id="content">


            <h3> Upload a new user document </h3>

        <h4><b> Step 1: <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userId" ng-blur="userIdChanged()"/>

            <div>{{email}}</div>

                 <br />

                        <input type="text" id="subjectP" placeholder="Subject line">
<textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="comment" id="notesP" placeholder="notes"></textarea>


<br />
        <h4><b> Step 2</b></h4>
                                <input type="button" value="Create Short" onclick="generateUpload();" /> <br/> <br/>


<div id="result"></div>



</div></div></div></div>

</div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Simon The button has arrived

Comment: Why would you get any errors?

Comment: Well your calling `gBenerateUpload()` on that button `onclick=`....?

Comment: `generateUpload` doesn't seem to actually _do_ anything. It just defines some variables and functions.

Comment: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: i forgot to add the button line. ive my updated my initial post

Comment: Looks like the button vanished again? In the code you provided for the button you spelt `generateUpload` wrong

Comment: below is the button       <input type="button" value="Create Short" onclick="generateUpload();" /> <br/> 
found in the body, and I want everything found in side generateUpload function be executed

Comment: I added the `google-api` tag, you should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Again, have you tried to debug your code???

Comment: The issue is that the google included script takes this as a parameter: `?onload=onApiLoad`.  You've now hidden that callback function away inside your `generateUpload` function so it's not there to be called in the global scope anymore.  IE this google script is designed to run on page load, not onclick.  You probably need to go re-read the API docs to see if it supports being invoked on demand rather than on page load.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will reread the API docs, but is there anyway I could get around that?

Comment: Perhaps hide the container element around whatever it's creating, and show that element on demand instead

Comment: could the button open another page that contains that code so that ?onload does apply, and then the item retrieved is shown in the orginal page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get it. You've set up the google API to call `onApiLoad` when it's finished loading. But that function doesn't exist in the global scope so you'll get an error.

The tricky part is that you want to run your code when you click your button *and* the google API has finished loading.

There are two ways to approach this:

1) Don't render the button until the Google API has finished loading. This involves rendering (or making visible) the button in you `onApiLoad` function.

That might not be feasible because of UI/UX stuff so there is a more complex solution:

2) Write a handler for the `onApiLoad` event:

```
var gapi_loaded = false, gapi_buffered_callbacks = [];
function onApiLoad() { // this function gets called by the Google API
    gapi_loaded = true;
    // run buffered callbacks
    for (var i = 0; i < gapi_buffered_callbacks.length; i += 1) {
        gapi_buffered_callbacks();
    }
}
function addOnOnApiLoadedCallback(callback) {
    if (gapi_loaded) {
        callback(); // api is loaded, call immediately
    } else {
        gapi_buffered_callbacks.push(callback); // add to callback list
    }
}
```

Then inside your `generateUpload` function add:

```
addOnOnApiLoadedCallback(onApiLoad);
```

---

Now as you can see this requires quite a bit of bookkeeping. Ideas have been developed to make this easier. `Promises` are one of them. If you want to explore more I suggest you start there.

---

Here is the full code:

```
function generateUpload() 
{

   // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = 'id';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var clientId = 'id';

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,

              'immediate': true
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
              enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
              addView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
                 var message = 'The following(s) were stored in Parse: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;

        }
      }

      addOnOnApiLoadedCallback(onApiLoad); // register API load
}

var gapi_loaded = false, gapi_buffered_callbacks = [];
function onApiLoad() { // this function gets called by the Google API
    gapi_loaded = true;
    // run buffered callbacks
    for (var i = 0; i < gapi_buffered_callbacks.length; i += 1) {
        gapi_buffered_callbacks();
    }
}
function addOnOnApiLoadedCallback(callback) {
    if (gapi_loaded) {
        callback(); // api is loaded, call immediately
    } else {
        gapi_buffered_callbacks.push(callback); // add to callback list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. It was incredibly useful, and I manage to get it work by creating a new html document and including that code in the header, and my input button in the footer. The side problem I have is that the button does not seem to be responding with my existing code (already had existing fields, and where that button was an additional compenent). I have included an update under my intial post. I would really appreciatre if you could kindly look into it

Comment: I don't know what the rest is supposed to do. I don't see how it ties together.

Comment: sorry and I know but its been a while, but for some reason I am having issue incorating this portion of code into my entire html document. If its not too much to ask would you could kindly edit your code with the current code included in the header and a button in the body, etc, for some reason i am having issue, thank]

Answer (score 0):

At first look its seems that you´re calling the function with a wrong name, you are calling it with gBenerateUpload and in the JQuery file it´s declared generateUpload

Comment: Why don´t you try with a button? All the code you´ve posted is in the HTML file or are they separates?

Comment: thanks. I did try with button and with support of this place, it manage to work. My issue now in lies in getting it to work with the existing code. I've included an update under my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach to this would be to put all the functions/variables etc back in the global scope as designed, and instead remove the `script` tag pointing at the Google script.  Instead, inject it in the click handler:

```
function generateUpload() 
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Injecting it like this doesn't change the situation. The google `api.js` actually injects more scripts. This is why the `onload` callback exists in the first place.

Comment: @Halcyon ah, ok thanks.  Does this actually put `onApiLoad` into a `window.onload` event handler then?

Comment: No. Basically when you call `api.js?onload=foo` it will _generate_ a script that, at the very end contains a call to `foo` (or whatever name you passed). If more scripts are loaded, the call to `foo` is delayed until those scripts have finished loading and setting up. It's similar to how `JSONP` works (JSON with padding).

Comment: @Halcyon ok - still unsure why that would make a difference then (if it's not using `window.onload` but is doing it's own callback, I'm not sure what difference loading the main script after the rest of the document would make) - but I've not used Google APIs, so will take your word for it :) This isn't the place to discuss it either, so I'll go investigate myself!